# Validating Start and End DateTimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a sample event ticketing app in Rails 4.1. I have a ticket model that checks the start and end dates and set the status of booking to open or close. Here's the code:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings
  belongs_to :user

  validates :ticket_name, :terms_conditions, presence: true
  validates_date :booking_start_date, on: :create, on_or_after: :today
  validates_date :booking_end_date, after: :booking_start_date
  validates :ticket_price, presence: true, numericality: true
  validates :ticket_quantity, :minimum_quantity, :maximum_quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  before_create :check_start_date
  before_update :check_start_date


    def check_start_date
        if (self.booking_start_date >= DateTime.now) 
            self.status = 'Open'
        elsif (self.booking_end_date == DateTime.now) && (ticket_quantity.to_i == 0)
            self.status = 'Closed'
        end
    end

    def maximum_tickets_allowed
        (1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
    end

end
```

The method check_start_date doesn't set the status to open if the start date and time is equal to current datetime. However, if I set the start date and time ahead even by a minute, the status is set as open. Am I using a wrong comparator here?

And second, I would like to know how to check the date time and set status to open or close. For example, today is August 11 and the bookings will start on Aug 13th. Now, how will I be able open bookings (meaning, change the status to "open" and unhide the 'Buy now' button) on that date automatically? Do I have to set up a cron job or is there another way?

Comment: Is booking start date a DateTime object?

Comment: @RSB yes, both booking start date and booking end date are DateTime objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the logic of `check_start_date` is wrong

it should be:

```
def check_start_date
    if(self.booking_start_date >= DateTime.now && DataTime.now < self.booking_end_date)
        if(self.ticket_quantity.to_i > 0) then  
          self.status = 'Open'
        else
          self.status = 'Sold Out'
        end
    elsif(DateTime.now < self.booking_start_date)
        self.status = 'Booking Available soon'

    elsif(DateTime.now >= self.booking_end_date)
        self.status = 'Closed'
    end
end
```

You need also to create a background cron job to keep checking the the booking status.

Answer (score 2):

**Method1:**

I suggest you to get rid of check_start_date, and use status method instead of status attribute.
Without a status attribute, you need not to maintain the status data.
With status method, you can always get the correct status based on system time and the ticket's booking_start_date and booking_end_date at realtime.

Status method:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  def status
    if self.booking_start_date >= Time.now && Time.now < self.booking_end_date
       && self.ticket_quantity.to_i > 0
       return 'Open'
    else
       return 'Closed'
    end
  end
end
```

**Method2:**

Get rid of check_start_date and status attribute first. In your controller code, you can get ticket  status by sql expression. If you have many application servers, and no Time Synchronizer between all servers, this method is better.

```
class TicketController< ApplicationController
  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.select("tickets.*, case when booking_start_date >= [current date] \
       and booking_end_date <= [current date] and ticket_quantity>0 then 'Open' \
       else 'Closed' end as status").find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @database }
    end
  end
end
```

**Note:** you should use your DBMS's current date function to replace [current date].